# my anchor tags are not working in my website after i added chart.js in it

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js, anchor

the issue is my anchor tags within the website was working fine,when i added chart.js for the graphs,once the charts gets loaded my anchor tag stops working,and if i disable them ,then anchor tags start working again

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
async function graph_final() {
  await getdata();
  document.querySelector(".box").style.display = "none";
  document.querySelector(".box2").style.display = "none";
  linechart();//calling graph 1
  linechart2();//calling graph2
}
graph_final();
```

if i comment graph 1 and graph 2 my anchor tag is working fine as when i click on them it redirecting to certain part of the same page(smooth scrolling)

**HTML PART**

```
<div class="nav-controls">
       <a href="#">DISABLED</a>
       <a href="#countrywise">COUNTRY STATUS</a>
       <a href="#top3">TOP 5 COUNTRIES</a>
 </div>
.
.
.
.
.
<div id="countrywise" class="mainsec-heading">
     <h3 class="mainsec-title"> SELECT BY COUNTRY</h3>
</div>
```

**LINECHART FUNCTION**

```
async function linechart() {
  const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
  Chart.defaults.global.defaultColor = "orange";
  const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "bar",
    data: {
      labels: labelsmonth,
      datasets: [{
        label: "NEW CASE",
        backgroundColor: [
          "coral",
          "lightgreen",
          "pink",
          "white",
          "lightblue",
        ],
        borderColor: ["black", "black", "black", "black", "black"],
        hoverBorderColor: "black",
        pointBackgroundColor: "#FFF",
        pointBorderColor: "#FFF",
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#000",
        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
        borderWidth: 2,
        data: datasfromapi,
      }, ],
    },
    options: {
      legend: {
        labels: {
          fontColor: "white",
          fontSize: 14,
        },
      },

      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            fontSize: 10,
            fontColor: "white",
            minRotation: 40,
            fontFamily: "Lato",
          },
          gridLines: {
            color: "black",
          },
        }, ],
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            fontSize: 10,
            beginAtZero: true,
            minRotation: 40,
            fontColor: "white",
          },
          gridLines: {
            color: "black",
          },
        }, ],
      },
    },
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you also post the code for `linechart()` and/or `linechart2()` since the problem is likely there.

Comment: linechart function added,linechart 2 is same just data is diff

Answer (score 0):

Probably a little late, but either way, put this in a js file and load this js file after loading the chart.js file.

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".page-header ul a");

for (const link of links) {
  link.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
}

function clickHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const href = this.getAttribute("href");
  const offsetTop = document.querySelector(href).offsetTop;

  scroll({
  top: offsetTop,
  behavior: "smooth"
});
```

}